# IBM Sterling File Gateway - iFix zip - unzip fails

Tags: unzip, ibm-sterling

While unzipping iFix file downloaded from Support Fix Central then it shows corrupted.

Comment: And how should anybody else help you out? Why not contact whoever provided that ZIP file?

Answer (score 0):

In case of any **Sterling File Gateway** **iFix** file with .zip extension downloaded from **IBM Fix Central** larger than 4 GB then use `jar -xvf <ifix file>` instead of unzip.